# How to get all user from LDAP in C# Using DirectoryEntry() or PrincipalContext()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

```
private void ADQuery()
{
    try
    {
        string connString = "LDAP://10.0.10.11/dc=abcd,dc=ac,dc=in";//demo url

        string username = "cn=admin,dc=abcd,dc=ac,dc=in";
        string name = "cn=admin,dc=abcd,dc=ac,dc=in";
        string password = "secrate";

        string name2 = "10.0.10.11\admin";//  domain\username
            
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(connString, name2, "secrate", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
          
        var search = new DirectorySearcher(de)
                         {   
                             Filter = "(&(ou=employee)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))"
                         };
        search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        // error thrown by this statement
        SearchResult results = search.FindOne();

        if (results != null)
        {
            string email = results.Properties["mail"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A local error has occurred.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>
> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A local error has occurred

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code, the only problem that stands out to me is your filter:

```
Filter = "(&(ou=employee)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))"
```

In Active Directory, the `inetOrgPerson` class is not used for users. If you want to find user objects, you should be using this as a filter:

```
Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))"
```

You also cannot filter on `ou` like you are trying to. To limit your search to a specific OU, use that OU in your LDAP string of the `DirectoryEntry` object that you're using for the [`SearchRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchroot). In your case, it's your `connString` variable:

```
string connString = "LDAP://10.0.10.11/OU=employee,dc=abcd,dc=ac,dc=in";
```

Also, `AuthenticationTypes.Secure` is the default [AuthenticationType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.authenticationtype), so you don't need to specify it in the constructor:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(connString, name2, "secrate", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Likewise, `Subtree` is the default [SearchScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.searchscope), so you don't need this line:

```
search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

Comment: I have implement as you have said but still getting same exception

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A local error has occurred. i think username i pass here it has some problem? [domain\user]

Comment: Your code shows you're using an IP address as the domain name: `10.0.10.11\admin`. That won't work. But if the user is on the same domain that you're connecting to, you don't need to include the domain at all. Just use the username.